# Why am I getting NullPointerException for null object array but the object has a default constructor?

Tags: java, arrays, object, constructor, nullpointerexception

I keep getting a `NullPointerException` for an array of objects I created that hasn't been initialized. But my player class has a default contructor so I assumed it would be fine. Why can't I call an instance method with these objects?

My main code block:

```
public class Blackjack{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Player[] p;
    p = new Player[6];
  }
}
```

And here is my player constructor:

```
public class Player {

    private int money;
    private int bet;
    private int handValue;

    // Player Constructor
    public Player() {
        handValue = 0;
        money = 100;
        this.bet = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After you instantiate the array, you must instantiate each individual element of the array with :

```
p[i] = new Player();
```

before you can call methods for those elements, since until you do that, `p[i]` contains `null` for each `i`.

Answer (score 1):

`Player[] p; p = new Player[6];` this will make `p` refer to an array of 6 null elements .  `new Player[6];` doesn't run the constructor

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are containers. In case of `Object`s they hold references. You can compare your code to

```
class PlayerContainerWith3Elements {
    public Player element0; // default initialized with null
    public Player element1;
    public Player element2;
}

PlayerContainerWith3Elements p = new PlayerContainerWith3Elements();
p.element0.helloNullPointer();
```

It's just much more convenient not to invent a class for every length and type and instead make a container via `new Player[3]`. But like a manual container, you have to set the reference for all the elements individually. In small arrays via the initializer syntax:

```
Player[] p = new Player[]{ new Player(), new Player(), new Player()};
// => makes a new Player[3] and puts the three objects in the 3 slots.
```

Anything larger with a loop

```
Player[] p = new Player[3];
for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
    p[i] = new Player();
```

Or in Java 8 you can do

```
Player[] p = Stream.generate(Player::new).limit(3).toArray(Player[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates an empty array of size `6`

```
Player[] p;
p = new Player[6];
```

`p` is now: `{ null, null, null, null, null, null }`

Instead, you want to fill this array with Player-objects, so try this instead:

```
Player[] p = new Player[6];
for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
    p[i] = new Player();
}
```

`p` is now: `{ aPlayerInstance1, aPlayerInstance2, aPlayerInstance3, aPlayerInstance4, aPlayerInstance5, aPlayerInstance6 }`